# Populating UITableView with XML data

Tags: xml, ios, uitableview, nsxmlparser, nsdata

I am parsing information from my server and have all the information being downloaded but having a rough time trying to figure out how to add the information to a table view. Basically what I would like to know is how to take the information I do have and add it to a NSMutableArray then count that object and add it to a table view but everytime I add my strings to a mutable array I get nothing... but I know all the information is being parsed correctly by my logs and a lable I placed just for testing purposes... here is the code I am using to get the information. how can I take the string I used and populate my table view?

```
     -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName   
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName   
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{


    NSLog(@"Parser Was Called");

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element"]) {
    NSLog(@"elements recieved %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"themeName"]);
    themeNameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict 
    objectForKey:@"themeName"]];
    //Test first string
    label.text = themeNameString;
     }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element1"]) {
    NSLog(@"elements recieved %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"creator"]);
    themeCreator = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict 
    objectForKey:@"creator"]];
    }    
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element2"]) {
    NSLog(@"elements recieved %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"price"]);
    themePrice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict 
    objectForKey:@"price"]];

    }      
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element3"]) {
    NSLog(@"elements recieved %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"twitterName"]);
    creatorTwitterName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict 
    objectForKey:@"twitterName"]];

      }  
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element4"]) {
    NSLog(@"elements recieved %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"themeURL"]);
    cydiaLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict 
    objectForKey:@"themeURL"]];

     }   
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element5"]) {
    NSLog(@"elements recieved %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"themeDeciption"]);
    deciption = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict 
    objectForKey:@"themeDeciption"]];

    }     

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element6"]) {
    NSLog(@"elements recieved %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"themeScreenShots"]);
    screenShots = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict 
     objectForKey:@"themeScreenShots"]];

    }        
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"element7"]) {
    NSLog(@"elements recieved %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"promo"]);
    tblViewImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [attributeDict 
     objectForKey:@"promo"]];

    } 

    }
```

Comment: Please put the code in code tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some basic doubts (its ok, we all had those), that's why I think you should learn by yourself to do that task (Information => Represent information on table). I would recommend you follow this tutorial:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/

It teaches how to, from a NSMutableArray, represents information on a table. Try that and if you have any doubt, you can ask me and I help you out.

Answer (score 0):

As for now I only see you using

```
– parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
```

To get all the xml data in an array you should have a little bit more. This is the documentatinoa bout NSXMLParser.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Depends on what you want, but I usually use

```
– parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
– parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:
– parser:foundCharacters:
```

But, again, it really depends on what you want as there are a lot more methods to choose from.